# GDB Backtrace Containing Similar Addresses but Different Source Lines

Tags: debugging, gdb, backtrace, virtual-address-space, debug-information

I was trying to debug `inkscape` and put a breakpoint at an address in its main shared library (i.e., `/usr/lib/inkscape/libinkscape_base.so`). When the execution reached that breakpoint, the backtrace was as follows:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6ecb220 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__priority=65535, __initialize_p=1) at /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:74
#1  0x00007ffff6ecb220 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_log_display_config.cpp(void) () at ./src/debug/log-display-config.cpp:83
#2  0x00007ffff7de5733 in call_init (env=0x7fffffffddd8, argv=0x7fffffffddc8, argc=1, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:72
#3  0x00007ffff7de5733 in _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe170, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffddc8, env=0x7fffffffddd8) at dl-init.c:119
#4  0x00007ffff7dd60ca in _dl_start_user () at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x0000000000000001 in  ()
#6  0x00007fffffffe176 in  ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in  ()
```

As can be seen, `#0` and `#1` point to the same address but different source locations. The same is true for `#2` and `#3`. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

> How is it possible?

It's possible with inlining.

GCC emits sufficient debug info for GDB to tell that a particular address, even though it is physically located inside `bar`, actually belongs to inlined `foo`.

Since `foo` is "not really there", but a call to it is *synthesized* by GDB in the `backtrace` output, what address GDB prints for it is somewhat irrelevant.

GDB used to print no address at all (my version `8.3.50.20190824-24.fc31` still does), but I guess this isn't dependable, and sometimes GDB may just repeat the previous return address.

Comment: Thanks. One thing to note is that there are many manual stack pointer modifications in the code including around this breakpoint, e.g., `add    $0x8,%rsp` and several lines after that we have `sub    $0x8,%rsp`. Can these lines make backtrace output unreliable?